# Total formulae in a theory equivalent to $\Delta_0$ formulae in the theory?

Tags: lo.logic, peano-arithmetic

Let a formula $\phi$ of the language of first-order Peano arithmetic be total in a theory Th that extends PA iff, for any $k_1, \dots, k_n \in \omega$, Th $\vdash \phi(\bar k_1, \dots, \bar k_n)$ or Th $\vdash \neg \phi(\bar k_1, \dots, \bar k_n)$. Is it true that total formulae in Th are provably equivalent in Th to $\Delta_0$ formulae?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

Certainly the statement is false for arbitrary theories.

For computably axiomatizable theories, it's still false; what follows is informal. Consider a uniformly computably axiomatizable sequence of theories $T_i$ which are *independent*: if I have a finite set $\{\varphi_i: i<n\}$ of formulas with each $\varphi_i$ either of the form $Con(T_i)$ or $\neg Con(T_i)$, then the conjunction of those formulas does not prove $Con(T_{n})$ or $\neg Con(T_{n})$.

Now let $Th$ be the theory gotten from PA by adjoining the axioms "$Con(T_i)$" for each $i\in\omega$. Then $Th$ is consistent and computably axiomatizable, and the formula $Con(T_x)$ is total in $Th$, but not provably $\Delta^0_1$.

And this can even be extended to finitely axiomatizable theories: take $$Th=PA+\neg Con(PA)+\forall x(Con(T_x)\text{ unless there is a $PA$-proof of 0=1 of length $<x$})$$ for appropriate choice of $T_i$.

Comment: If Th is recursively axiomatisable, is there a $\Sigma_1$ formula in the language of the theory that defines totality?

Comment: No. Consider the formula $\psi_T(x)=$"Either there is no proof that $T$ is inconsistent of length $<x$, or $PA$ is consistent" as $T$ ranges over finitely axiomatizable theories. Then $\psi_T(x)$ is $PA$-total iff $T$ is consistent, so if totality were c.e., the consistency of finitely axiomatizable theories would be computable.

Comment: Basically, as a rule of thumb, anything defined in terms of "true" $\omega$ (as totality is) is going to be poorly behaved, model-theoretically . . .

Comment: But in PA you can. I'd like to have it specifically in PA + $\forall x(Bew\ (\neg x) \rightarrow \neg Bew(x))$. Is there a counterexample too?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand: in the phrases "in PA you can [???]" and "I'd like to have [???] specifically in . . .", it's not clear to me what you are referring to. For what it's worth, the argument I've given shows that for any "reasonable" theory $T$, the set of $T$-total formulae is not c.e., which is very general . . .

Comment: (Also, in this context, it's good to give the provability predicate "$Bew$" a subscript, i.e., $Bew_{PA}(x)$ instead of $Bew(x)$.)

Comment: I'm sorry. I got confused. I thought PA-total formulae were PA-equivalent to $\Delta_0$ formulae.